# Are there any SMS gateways for only sending messages that don't require buying a short code?

Tags: api, sms, message, sms-gateway, gateway

I need to send SMS messages from my app to users with status updates, but I don't like the "send an email to their phone numbers" route because the messages typically includes lots of cruft (like "FRM" and "MSG" and other random things).

I know I could get my own short code and use a service like Twilio or Clickatell, but short codes are out of my price range right now.

So are there any SMS gateways that let me use some sort of generic, random short code for only sending messages? I don't need any ability for users to reply to the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few options for you, all with varying APIs:

- [tropo.com](https://www.tropo.com/)
- [torpedeiro.com](http://torpedeiro.com)
- [twilio.com](http://www.twilio.com)
- [springedge.com](https://www.springedge.com)

Probably also depends on where your users are, pretty sure Twilio only service US & Canada.

Comment: I know this was answered years ago. But it is important to note (for search engine results that arrive on this page) that Twilio services pretty much every country now.

Answer (score 1):

At work we use [RedOxygen](http://www.redoxygen.com) for sending SMS messages. They don't require you to have a short code and sending using their gateway uses a phone number on their side. They do allow you to obtain responses to your SMS's via a limited API as well.

Feel free to shop around though, this isn't an endorsement.

Answer (score 0):

Global SMS delivery doesn't rely on having short codes available in each country you're targetting so many SMS Gateways will allow you to send from a 'broadcast' account without the necessity to rent a shortcode.

Renting a shortcode would only be really necessary if you wanted inbound traffic too which you've stated you don't.

Sending an SMS using an 11 character alphanumeric identifier is possible in many countries and for those with delivery restrictions requiring sending through shortcodes then the SMS Gateway should do the work for you to ensure your message is delivered whatever the restrictions.

[Disclaimer: I work for Esendex, a global SMS Gateway]

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to any of the SMS Providers or SMS Gateways (either local or Global), and ask them to provide you an HTTP or XML API. Then you can make your system capable of sending auto SMS using these APIs. This must work